# Primefaces Layout with 100% height

Tags: css, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Is there a way to set the height of a `<p:layout>` to 100% of the remaining space? (fullPage="false")

Answer (score 0):

I can use the style attribute of the layout:

```
 <p:layout fullPage="false" style="width:100%;height:100%">

</p:layout>
```